# Facebook Samsung S3 permission screen

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated Facebook SDK 3.0 in my application following this tutorial:- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/#enablesso

I have integrated Facebook login into my application, Every thing works fine, but I get this permission screen when a user tries to login in first time to my application on Samsung S3, Android OS - 4.1.2. I have looked a lot on internet but there is no doc that says this screen comes by default. This permission screen is only for the first time. Next time this screen dosent comes for the logged in user, but if a new user logs in to the same phone again this permission screen comes up.

I have also installed the same build on Samsung Grand phone, O.S version - 4.1,
Is it something to do with this OS version, I dont get this screen on any other phone with OS version 4.0 or below.

Please help me with some solution on how to overcome this issue or tell user that this is because of latest OS version.

[image]

Comment: Default is that the user has to allow your facebook app to do what it requests permissions to do. So what is the actual question?

Comment: Actual question is why do i get this permission dialog, only on phones with OS version 4.1.x and not on other OS. And if this behavior is default then there should be a document for this. Also, Why this screen says Samsung Galaxy S III, instead it should say My application Name.

Comment: @DavidOlsson do you have any idea why this happens when from my app i try to sso fb login but samsung tab ask permission for facebook and if i denied my app crashes?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the matter of any os it's related to the facebook itself, try to install any facebook app on even browser like farmville you will see this screen there too.

You must specify the requested permissions while registering your app on the facebook.
and client must grant them to access the facebook features.

Yes this appears only for the first time for every facebook account you use. 
Like before installing a application in android it asks for all the permissions.

It need not be documented,it's obvious

Comment: Then why i dont get the same screen or similar kind of permission screen on other phones considering same situation

Comment: do you have the facebook native application installed on the S3 and not installed on the Grand

Comment: I have native FB installed, but not signed into Facebook app, I tap on my app sign in with a FB user who has never logged into Fb in this phone. Here is the point where i get this screen. Even if i tap on cancel on this screen i get through the sign in process, but the question is it the default behavior with OS 4.1. Also I tried using other app which have latest SDK of FB, there also I am getting the same screen, only on OS 4.1.

Comment: Why is this behaviour fb should only ask for the specific app permissions??why samsung's is asking for fb permissions??and i denied the app crashes

Comment: @MuhammadBabarI feel this happens on devices in which, user has never logged in to FB(new device, Fb uninstall and then reinstall and never logged in to FB), Thus, with new SDK 3.0 of FB, no matter, which app is accessing FB, but if user has never logged in it will ask only for first time. Thus to test, on a new device with latest OS, may be samsung device, dont log in to FB and launch any app that has FB 3.0 SDK, and try to use FB feature on that app, u would see this permission. Now accept it and then launch your app, this time and here after you would never see the above permission screen.

Comment: @Ali I guess this feature is some what related with new fb app not the Api level (4.1)? may be i'm wrong but that's what seems to me, any way thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this issue. i then did a search and found this page. for some reason installing facebook on a galaxy s3 causes facebook to automatically try to install a galaxy s3 facebook app.

They set it up to pop up when you first log in so that it seems like part of the facebook installation, when it's really almost forcing you to install a facebook app you may not want.

i had to hit 'cancel' twice before it would let me actually log into facebook without adding their app.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it answers the question. It was a good try though. Answers should answer the actual question; not one that is related.